# Excel-Dna Build is Cutting in Front of Pre-Build Event

Tags: excel-dna

We have a .NET 6 UDF project that has a Pre-Build event script (written in PowerShell) specified in the project's build properties. The script generates a .dna file whose content varies based on arguments passed to the PowerShell script. The name of the generated .dna file depends on the arguments passed to the PowerShell script. (There's also a Post-Build clean-up script but that's irrelevant for this discussion.)

The name of the Project is, `RiskTools`.

The pre-Build script should, to my understanding, run *before* the project begins building. But take a look at these two lines of output from the Build Log:

```
2>ExcelDnaSetLaunchSettings: Add-In for debugging: bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\RiskTools-AddIn-64.xll
2>***** PRE BUILD STEP STARTING
```

The second line represents the start of execution of the Pre-Build script. Notice the first line though. The ExcelDna (is it the build task?) has already determined the name of the generated .XLL file. It has made this determination *before* the Pre-Build script even started execution and before the .dna file could be generated!

The problem is that we do not want the name of the XLL file to be determined until *after* the Pre-Build step completes and the .dna file has been generated. Is there anything we can do to adjust this? The default XLL file name, `RiskTools-Addin-64.xll` is wrong, as are its contents.

Our Pre-Build script works correctly and generates a valid .dna file which is promptly ignored by the Exce-DNA Build task.

Comment: We could try to find a way to use the project properties instead of the .dna files. With newest version we should be able to work out a way to do this. The Excel-DNA Google group is best for this kind of support. https://groups.google.com/g/exceldna